# What is the difference between using request objects and not using them while doing fetch calls?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Basically what is difference between:

```
const req = new request(url, requestOptions);
const res = fetch(request)
.then(response => JSON.parse(response));
```

AND

```
const res = fetch(url, requestOptions)
.then(response => JSON.parse(response));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is: `request` function is not ready in the DOM by default.

```
// by default
// console.log(typeof request); // undefined

const req = new request(url, requestOptions);
```